# Recommended UX events and event news sources?

Tags: resources, education, books, conferences

As ux professionals:

- what events do you make a point of attending? (whether for education, networking, etc)
- why? (what benefits do you feel you gain)
- what is your go-to source for finding out about new/upcoming events?

Some of the ones I've already attended &/or heard good things about include:

- UPA events, UX Book Club, and IA in the pub meetings (events mentioned by Alex Horstmann -thanks Alex- in relation to the earlier question "[Career building: mentoring, volunteering, and/or networking?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/4590/career-building-mentoring-volunteering-and-or-networking)"
- [IDEA conference](http://ideaconference.org/2009/Home)
- [UX Book Club Toronto](http://groups.google.com/group/uxbcto?pli=1)
- [Toronto Geek Girls](http://www.torontogirlgeekdinners.ca/)
- IxDA [meetings](http://www.ixda.org/discuss.php?post=47737&search=ixda+toronto), [Interaction conference](http://interaction.ixda.org/)
- [UX Irregulars](http://groups.google.ca/group/UXIrregulars?pli=1)
- [Refresh Events](http://refresh-events.ca/)

Do folks have any additional details, feedback, recommendations about other (or the above) events to share?

Sep 24 update: Adding this additional resource for ux events that I came across today in case it's helpful to others: http://finduxevents.com/

Comment: All this, and you want more?! ;)

Comment: LOL, guess I just love to soak as much UX up as I can! My main interest in posing the question is to see what other people who've attended any of the above thought of them (since I haven't attended them all) and also to find out if there are any really worthwhile things out there that I might have missed so far and should make a point of checking out :)

Comment: Adding an additional (Toronto) resource I just came across for Toronto Social Media Events (though social media-focussed, many of the events will still likely be relevant for many ux'ers): http://toprsocialmediaevents.pbworks.com/

Answer (score 7):

You might find the [calendar of events](http://interaction-design.org/calendar/) provided by [interaction-design.org](http://interaction-design.org) useful. It's very comprehensive and available in a number of formats.

I'd also recommend attending any unconference events in your local area. I've had a fantastic time at various BarCamps.

You'll probably find a local [UX Book Club](http://uxbookclub.org) in your area (or you could always set up your own.)

Answer (score 5):

I found [London IA Ning group](http://london-ia.ning.com/) to be a good source of events taking place in the city. Also Twitter seems to be a good source of information if it comes to UX events.

I recently try to attend anything that's available and is either free or fairly cheap – I'm still learning so networking and talking with experienced people is the most important bit at this point, which means meetups and book clubs have the highest priority.

Answer (score 4):

For people that are following this thread in the UK, a great source of UX events listings is [the Events page of Usability News](http://www.usabilitynews.com/default.asp?c=3).

Answer (score 3):

Stuart Cruickshank has recently created a [calendar of UX Events in London](http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=5iaao7piic3jkh3vvei44ujl08@group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe/London). It's London-specific (it does include some Brighton-based events as well), but it's useful for those who live in the area.

Answer (score 2):

I am interested in this too.  Last month, I went to Business of Software 2009.  I thought it was fantastic and perfect for UX designers. (http://businessofsoftware.org/speakers.aspx)

I've heard great things about SxSW (http://sxsw.com/)

Is there a local UX group in your area?  It's usually helpful to network locally.  That's an easy way to find out about events.

Answer (score 2):

Another great event is UX London - I went last year and thoroughly recommend it. See: http://2010.uxlondon.com/

Comment: +1 for UX London

It was really good last year and I'll be going again this year

Comment: +1 well worth it. Missed out this year due to it falling on my wedding day, fingers crossed the 2011 event isn't the same week or I'll have to settle for UXLX in Portugal.

Answer (score 1):

If you were in Australia you could attend UX Australia :) Or if in Portugal; UX Lisbon (which Donna Spencer, one of the organisers of UX Australia is attending and presenting at next year).

Answer (score 1):

http://LessConf.com

Answer (score 1):

There is a great new site that tracks events via twitter - http://lanyrd.com/ I'm finding that the best way to see what events are on the horizon and as it's linked to twitter I can see who I am following who are also interested.

As for UX related events I go to:

- LondonIA
- UX Book Club - London
- UXLondon
- UXBrighton
- and hoepfully in Nov UX People

Non related are:

- RSA talks
- Playful

Answer (score 0):

UX Intensive! http://adaptivepath.com/events/2010/uxi/

Answer (score 0):

LBi have created (and maintain) a Google calendar of all forthcoming UX events in the UK. Well worth a look:

http://www.google.com/calendar/embed?src=5iaao7piic3jkh3vvei44ujl08%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=Europe/London